What's the IN clause for this query?
I'm new to data analytics and I'm trying to study subqueries.
The lecture is asking to pull up all the number of hospitalizations using the FDA events data from the BigQuery public data.
I tried to write a query that doesn't use a subquery and I also copied the query written in the lecture and compared the results.
No subquery used:
SELECT
  DISTINCT products_industry_name,
  COUNT(report_number) AS count_hospitalization
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.fda_food.food_events`
WHERE
  outcomes LIKE '%Hospitalization%'
GROUP BY products_industry_name
ORDER BY count_hospitalization DESC
LIMIT 10;

Subquery was used:
SELECT
  products_industry_name,
  COUNT(report_number) AS count_hospitalizations
FROM
  bigquery-public-data.fda_food.food_events
WHERE 
  products_industry_name IN
    (SELECT
      products_industry_name
     FROM
      bigquery-public-data.fda_food.food_events
     GROUP BY products_industry_name
     ORDER BY COUNT(report_number) DESC 
     LIMIT 10)
  AND outcomes LIKE '%Hospitalization%'
GROUP BY products_industry_name
ORDER BY count_hospitalizations DESC;

After running both queries, the first few rows match one another, but, when it gets to the bottom portion of the return tables,the values are different. The only huge difference between the query is the IN clause included in the second query, and I would like to understand why both return values have different results.

Well, the subquery does not use distinct and the "other" query does so these are not the same query. Also the subquery applies the LIKE criteria after grouping (after the grouping in the subquery anyway), and the "other" query applies the LIKE criteria before grouping.

@topsail, so the number of groupings for the second query affected the return values, is what I'm getting. I think I'm getting it now, thanks for pointing that out!

I would probably step back and ask what are you trying to do? The queries are different enough that the reason they are different is that they are not the same. Do you need to fix one or both of these queries? What is the problem now?

@topsail, I was under the impression that since the first parts of the queries are the same, they would have the same results. I think I need to try out more queries to see it more clearly, thank you for this!!
